# Interpolating values in HTML attributes - Pug (Jade)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to construct an `anchor` tag with a dynamic `href` attribute in Jade.

I did go through the [docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/) and some SO questions but they didn't help me. This is what I tried.

```
a(href= "http://www.imdb.com/title/#{movie.imdb_id}") Know more
```

But it renders

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/#{movie.imdb_id}
```

rather than

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1234567
```

However this works

```
a(href= "http://www.imdb.com/title/" + movie.imdb_id) Know more
```

and this too.

```
- var url = "http://www.imdb.com/title/" + movie.imdb_id;
  a(href= url) Know more
```

What's wrong with the first version?

Answer (score 17):

Interpolation is only available in text.

You need to use JS string concatenation for attributes:

```js
a(href="http://www.imdb.com/title/" + movie.imdb_id) Know more
```

If you JavaScript runtime supports [ES2015 template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you can also use them (notice the backticks):

```js
a(href=`http://www.imdb.com/title/${movie.imdb_id}`) Know more
```

[Reference](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation)

Answer (score 3):

the pug variable declaration doesnt work in this case using `#{...}`
the right syntax goes this way,

```
a(attributes) Know more

a(href="http://www.imdb.com/title/"+ movie.imdb_id) Know more
```

the attributes is an expression so it renders correcly, or you could use ES5 template literals with back quotes to render the variable along side the text which becomes

```
a(href=`http://www.imdb.com/title/${movie.imdb_id}`) Know more
```

note that when using back quotes  with template literals your variable expression are enclosed in parenthesis and a leading `$` sign, that is `${..expression..}`

Answer (score 0):

When you quote it simply tells pug "this is a string". That's basic JS. `Interpolation works with #{'#{interpolation}'} too!` is an example which renders "Interpolation works with #{interpolation} too!"

Comment: Look through the examples on https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html

Answer (score -3):

I don't have any knowledge about pug(jade)

But my guess is `"a(your code)"` is already a signal to pug(jade) that it is in the controller's scope already.. and `"{variable}"` is also an indicator that you are accessing controller's scope. so

```
a(href= "http://www.imdb.com/title/#{movie.imdb_id}") Know more
```

for `"{}"` inside `a()` is no longer an indicator that your are trying to access controller's scope because you're already in the controller's scope.. so `"{}"` inside `a()` is just a string, `{movie.imdb_id}` is part of the link string.

So in order for the framework to identity that `movie.imdb_id` is a variable, you should separate it from the actual string.

NOTE: This is just a guess..I'm using angular